# How can I change the update speed of the resource monitor?

Tags: windows-7, resource-monitor, refresh

In Windows 7, the resource monitor updates about once a second, but I find this too slow. In Task Manager you can make it update about twice a second, or tens of times if you manually refresh it.

F5 doesn't work in the resource monitor for me.

**Is there a change in the registry that I can make to change the update speed, or manually refresh resource monitor?**

Comment: This one of those April fools things?

Comment: No, genuine question. I can't find an option for it at all.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sickest Not even a change in the registry?

Comment: Could always write your own if you are not satisfied with the current one :)

Comment: @George Leonard Severt of the Microsoft Performance Team noted that, `...resmon.exe is hard coded to 1 second intervals and cannot be changed. If you need higher intervals, then create a User Defined Data Collector set.` Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/01/using-resource-monitor-to-troubleshoot-windows-performance-issues-part-1/   Data Collector Set information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414.aspx

Comment: @root your comment should be an answer.

Comment: Can I improve my question somehow to get rid of the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leonard Severt of the Microsoft Performance Team [noted](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/01/using-resource-monitor-to-troubleshoot-windows-performance-issues-part-1/) that, `...resmon.exe is hard coded to 1 second intervals and cannot be changed. If you need higher intervals, then create a User Defined Data Collector set.`

More on [Data Collector sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414.aspx).